# How to run multiple scripts in sequence using command prompt

Tags: perl, batch-file, command-line, tcl, stdin

I need to do some kind of modification in post-synthesis hardware description language (HDL) files of field-progammable gate array (FPGA) design. I am using Microsemi's *Libero* system on chip (SoC) tool for that design process.

Totally, it has three different design processes such as

1. Pre-modification process
2. Modification process
3. Post-modification process on HDL codes

All three steps need to be performed in sequence using the Windows command line. I wrote a Tcl script for the first and third processes and a Perl script for the second process. In the first and third processes, some FPGA design tools for synthesis, simulation, place and route will be called through the command line.

This is the overall idea of the work. My question is how can I run all three different scripts (Tcl, Perl and Tcl) in sequence using a single script (or any other file format) in command line?

**Note**: In few steps, it is required to get user data through STDIN. I am working in windows platform..

Comment: Is there any reason why you can'd just put the three commands into a shell command file and run that?

Comment: `cmd.exe` can run pipelines. Even `command.com` did that back in the bad old DOS days, and always could since as far back as I can remember or search. You just gotta make each script read from stdin and write to stdout…

Comment: To Borodin....i am not much aware of shell command file, so i dint try it out... any relevant document or sample code will be highly help full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file (extension .bat) something like:

```
start /b tcl script1
start /b perl script1
start /b tcl script2
```

Comment: Thank you Sharad... It runs all the scripts simultaneously,  but i want in sequence, i.e. script2 should start after completion of script1...

Comment: Sequential should be simpler. Remove 'start /b' and the commands will run sequentially.

Comment: yeah its working...as i mentioned in note, while executing perl script, i need to get user data through STDIN, is it possible to get user data when a perl script is run through batch file??

Comment: Yes. Remove the /b flag and try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with `Tcl` but an example using `Perl` would be (from the `DOS` command-line):

```
perl hi.pl > log.txt & perl mid.pl >> log.txt & perl low.pl >> log.txt
```

The 3 `perl` script run in succession with the output of all 3 scripts put in a file called log.txt.

You can incorporate `STDIN` as needed.